# Existence of infinite number of infinite cardinals st:

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Prove the existence of infinite number of infinite cardinals

1) $\alpha$, such that  $\alpha<\alpha^\aleph$

2) $\beta$, such that  $\beta=\beta^\aleph$

Comment: You might want to look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question for some tips on asking questions here (even if this isn't homework).

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is quite a bit harder than the second.

For $1$), use [König's theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28set_theory%29)  We still then need to show that, for example, there are infinitely many cardinals of cofinality say $\omega$, but that part is not hard.  For suppose we start at the infinite cardinal $\kappa_0$. Let $\kappa_1=2^{\kappa_0}$, $\kappa_2=2^{\kappa_1}$, and so on, and let $\kappa_\omega=\bigcup \kappa_n$. Then $\kappa_\omega$ has a right cofinality, and König's theorem applies. For the next one, start at $\kappa_\omega$.

For $2$), we can use for $\beta$ anything of shape say $\kappa^\aleph$, where $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal.

Comment: Actually just taking $\alpha=\kappa^{+\omega}$ would ensure that $\alpha$ has countable cofinality.

Comment: Yes, I am taking (possibly) larger hops than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Using $\aleph$ as a general cardinal might be ambiguous (there are places where it is used particularly for $2^{\aleph_0}$), the answer remains the same regardless to the intended use of $\aleph$.

1. Recall that for every infinite $\kappa$ we have $\kappa<\kappa^{\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)}$. Simply show that there are infinitely many cardinals whose cofinality is $\aleph$. You can show that there exists a sequence $\alpha_0<\alpha_0^\aleph<\alpha_1<\ldots$ by starting the construction of $\alpha_{n+1}$ from the construction of $\alpha_n^\aleph$.
2. Cardinal exponentiation has the property $\left(\kappa^\lambda\right)^\mu=\kappa^{\lambda\cdot\mu}$. Take $\alpha$ from the previous part and take $\beta=\alpha^\aleph$, now we have $\beta^\aleph=\alpha^{\aleph\cdot\aleph}=\alpha^\aleph=\beta$.

Note that for the second part you don't *really* need the first part, however it is easy to show that there are infinitely many $\beta$ if you use the fact that $\alpha_n^\aleph\neq\alpha_k^\aleph$ for $n\neq k$.

Comment: If anyone is interested, there's a short proof of the OP's question in the case of $\aleph_{0}$ at http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/msg/324c39aa393fa801 Like Asaf Karagila's argument, it shows slightly more than what was asked by showing the existence of arbitrarily large such cardinals, and not just infinitely many such cardinals.